# Newman: ReferenceError: pm is not defined

Tags: postman, newman

Hi I could use `pm` in my `Postman` (Standalone).  The code was something like:

```
let someData = pm.response.json().data;
```

But when I ran a similar script run in `Newman`, I got this error:

```
ReferenceError: pm is not defined
```

According to this [discussion](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/1439), Newman since 3.6.0 should support `pm`, and I was using  4.2.3.   What did I miss?

Comment: Not sure but `pm.response.json().data` will give you null always! it should be only `pm.response.json()`, and seems fine with newman 4.2.3, not an issue at all, please add more detail to the question

Comment: That would return anything in that `data` property, if the reponse contains it. `pm.response.json()` Parses the response like `JSON.parse(responseBody)`. What version are you using to export the collection? Newman 4 only works with v2 collections I think.

Comment: @Div -- `data` is a property of the response that I am processing.  @Danny --  I was exporting using v2.1.0  I can try again using v2.  Thanks!